# How to add a tooltip for a datagrid and show the converted value of the datagrid in tooltip?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, tooltip, datagridcell

I have DataGrid and one of the DataGrid columns looks like this.

```
<ig:TextColumn HeaderText="{Binding CARTONS, Source={StaticResource Messages}, Converter={StaticResource MessageConverter}}" 
    Key="Column1" AllowToolTips="Always">
    <ig:TextColumn.ToolTipContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Self}, Converter={StaticResource TransferColumnToCrlfDelimitedList}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ig:TextColumn.ToolTipContentTemplate>
</ig:TextColumn>
```

The problem is I need show convert the column's value to a list of sub-value of the column. I tried using self. Obviously, it doesn't work.

How can I solve my task? Is any possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove SELF 
Use just {Binding} and you will get the same DataContext as the parent control